# Headless UI Combobox (Autocomplete): Removing input after selecting a user

Tags: javascript, vue.js, combobox, nuxt.js, headless-ui

I'm using the Headless UI library's Combobox component in a Vue project. My setup involves using the combobox for multiple selections. Everything is working as expected, except for one aspect: I can't seem to clear the ComboboxInput value after making a selection.

Here's my current code setup:

```js
<template>
  <Combobox v-model="selectedUsers" multiple>
    <!-- ... rest of the component ... -->
    <ComboboxInput
      @change="query = $event.target.value"
      :displayValue="(user) => user.name"
      class="w-full text-sm py-2 focus:outline-none focus-visible:outline-none rounded-lg"
      placeholder="Mitarbeiter hinzufügen..."
    />
    <!-- ... rest of the component ... -->
  </Combobox>
</template>

<script setup>
  // ... imports ...

  const selectedUsers = ref([]);
  const query = ref('');

  // ... rest of the setup code ...
</script>
```

What I'm aiming for is to have the input field (ComboboxInput) clear out every time I select an option. I've tried several methods, such as using the @select event, manually changing the value using refs, and watching the v-model to detect changes, but nothing seems to work.

Anyone here who has an idea how to clear the input after making a selection (with mouse or keyboard)?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to solve the exact same problem in react, used `document.getElementbyID` to clear out as a workaround, but definitely not a great react solution.

What worked for me eventually was to add a key with selected.length to force re-render.

`key={selectedUsers.length}`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. It does clear the input, but it also loses focus. So I have to click on it again. Any idea how to make it keep focus?

Comment: I think vue should have something similar, but I used useEffect to listen to the changes of the selected array to refocus.

Answer (score 0):

Using the preventdefault method within an event handler function shuts down the default behavior and puts you in control of the entire event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault